# Swift class/struct doesn't update self property from dispatched queue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I've just started learning Swift/UI from writing own project.

I have two classes/structs:

```
import SwiftUI

struct WordList: View {
    @State var current: Int? = nil
    
    init() {
        SpeechPlayer.shared.subscribeOnCurrentUpdated(self.onCurrentUpdated)
    }
    
    public func onCurrentUpdated(_ current: Int?) -> Void {
        self.current = current
        print(self.current, current) // <-- current = 1, but self.current = nil 
    }

    var body: some View {
    ...
```

```
import Foundation

class SpeechPlayer {
    
    static let shared = SpeechPlayer()
    
    private var current: Int = 0
    private var onCurrentUpdateSubscribers: [(_ current: Int?) -> Void] = []
    
    private init() {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            while true {
                self.current += 1
                DispatchQueue.global().async {
                    self.onCurrentUpdateSubscribers.forEach { callback in
                        callback(self.current)
                    }
                }
                sleep(1)
            }
        }
    }

    public func subscribeOnCurrentUpdated(_ callback: @escaping (_ current: Int?) -> Void) -> Void {
        self.onCurrentUpdateSubscribers.append(callback)
    }

}
```

The problem is when the function `onCurrentUpdated` is called, self.current is not updated and still equals nil, but param `current` equals a number.

I would really appreciate for any help.

Comment: Consider to use an `ObservableObject` running on the `@MainActor` and a`@Published` property. That's more *SwiftUI-ish*. And **never ever** `sleep` (unless in a Swift Concurrency `Task`) and use weird `while true` loops

Comment: Actually it is conceptually incorrect, the `subscribeOnCurrentUpdated` copies view (because it is a value, but not a reference), so callback is sent to something in memory but not to an original view. Move all this into view model as recommended above.

Comment: @Asperi, Thats right, so I need to pass reference of the view, I will check this

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you dispatch some work onto a shared global queue and then you block that queue with `sleep` (never do that).  Because the queue is blocked it can't make any progress.  To enqueue some work after 1 second use: `DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1)`

In addition, you have written code that reads the value of `current` on the main thread but reads and writes it (`self.current += 1`) on a background thread.  That's not safe because there's no synchronization to ensure correct reads/writes.  Either always use a consistent queue e.g. main queue to read/modify this variable or consider using an `actor` type, so that the compiler will not allow mistakes like that.

Comment: Thank you, I block the shared queue for 1 sec to reduce looping time ticks, .asyncAfter postpone execution with delay that's not what I need to. I need dig into threads, because I would like to have like a daemon for Player which does his job so I use `while true`, but you mentioned actors. I will read about it, thank you again.